# How to make the user open a url new tab after clicking a specific button inside <body> , but can only declare on <footer>

Tags: javascript, php, html

I just started learning html css and JavaScript, and I have a problem. I need to make the visitor to open an extra tab with specific url after clicking a button. This specific url is actually a thankyou page, so that after they finished filling out a form and click the button 'Register', they don't just got redirected to a new page, but also open an extra tab.

The button inside the body tag is declared in this code:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-masuk fw-bold" value="Daftar" style="margin-top:20px; width:200px; text-align: center; display: grid; place-items: center; line-height: var(--text-size-default); height: 40px" id="buttonRegister">
```

### My problem

Now, the original script works fine but I don't know how to make the auto open extra tab after clicking that button, plus I cannot edit anything inside the body tag since its a template cms, including the button code itself, I can only add some script at the footer text or head meta.

I don't know if I should add an extra JavaScript code or whatever else to make this work.

Comment: If you can not modify the HTML directly, then you will need to use a script that selects the button, and adds a click event handler to it. But - this pattern, of opening _two_ pages on _one_ click interaction, is often used to try and open additional advertising pages - so there is chance, that this might just get blocked by a popup blocker.

Comment: for now i can assume that its fine since i just want this to works. any help on the script?

Answer (score 1):

If you're unable to modify the HTML directly but can add script tags to the footer or head meta, you can use JavaScript to attach a click event listener to the button and open a new tab when it is clicked. Here's an example script you can add to the footer or head meta

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var registerButton = document.getElementById("buttonRegister");

if (registerButton) {
    registerButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var thankYouPageUrl = "https://example.com/thankyou";
        window.open(thankYouPageUrl, '_blank');
    });
}
```

});

Comment: its not working. I've tried to put the code inside both footer nor head meta, i changed the url but still nothing works. is there anything i should've change other than the thankyoupage url, based on the button code? Idk if i've made some silly mistakes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Check Console for Errors:
Open your browser's developer tools (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking on the page and selecting "Inspect"), navigate to the "Console" tab, and see if there are any error messages. They might provide insights into what's going wrong.

Ensure DOM Content Loaded:
Make sure that the script is loaded after the DOM content has fully loaded. You can place your script just before the closing  tag to ensure it runs after the DOM is ready.

Verify Button ID:
Confirm that the ID used in the script matches the actual ID of your "Register" button. The script is looking for an element with the ID "buttonRegister."

Script Placement:
Try placing the script directly in the HTML body, just after the button element. If you can't modify the body directly, try placing it as the last element in the footer. Ensure there are no other scripts interfering.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-masuk fw-bold" value="Daftar" style="margin-top:20px; width:200px; text-align: center; display: grid; place-items: center; line-height: var(--text-size-default); height: 40px" id="buttonRegister">

<!-- Script in the Footer -->
<script>
  var registerButton = document.getElementById("buttonRegister");

  if (registerButton) {
      registerButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          var thankYouPageUrl = "https://example.com/thankyou";
          window.open(thankYouPageUrl, '_blank');
      });
  }
</script>
```

After making these adjustments, refresh your page and test the button again. If the issue persists, let me know if there are any error messages in the console, and we can continue troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" window.open('http://google.com','_blank')"> Google</button>
```

Comment: this can works but only if i have the access to edit the element inside the body tag which i can't. i can only put some script inside the head meta or the footer text tag